# How to append two completely different data sets in python?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, jupyter-notebook, concatenation

I have to append two data sets. They have completely different rows and columns. I have tried the command: 
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2)but it gives an error.[Data Frame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr1qg.jpg)
[Data Frame 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnhSh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

if they have the same number of columns and are on the same order, you could do :

```py
df2.columns = df1.columns 
df_concat = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```